# How to bind a collection of values to a jOOQ batch insert

Tags: java, java-8, jooq

I have a collection of objects, which I'd love to insert as a batch. 
First I thought "for-loops", but then it dawned on me that this should be doable with streams.

```
BatchBindStep userLoginBatch = create
    .batch(
            create.insertInto(USERLOGIN, USERLOGIN.USERNAME, USERLOGIN.IP, USERLOGIN.MAC, USERLOGIN.LOGIN, USERLOGIN.STATUS, USERLOGIN.APPLICATION, USERLOGIN.ENTERTAINMENT_CREDENTIALS_ID, USERLOGIN.VERSION)
                    .values(null, null, null, (Timestamp) null, null, null, (Integer) null, null)
    );

userLoginsToPersist
  .stream()
  .map(login ->
        Arrays.asList(login.getUsername(), login.getIp(), login.getMac(), login.getLogin(), login.getStatus(), login.getApplication(), login.getEntertainmentCredentialsId(), login.getVersion())
  ).reduce(userLoginBatch, (a, b) -> a.bind(b));
userLoginBatch.execute();
```

This is what I currently have and it's complaining that I can't reduce on that object...

Comment: I've never used jOOQ but guessing from your source code, maybe you could replace the reduce call with `forEach(b -> userLoginBatch.bind(b));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
userLoginsToPersist
  .stream()
  .map(login ->
        Arrays.asList(login.getUsername(), login.getIp(), login.getMac(), login.getLogin(), login.getStatus(), login.getApplication(), login.getEntertainmentCredentialsId(), login.getVersion())
  ).reduce(userLoginBatch, (b, v) -> b.bind(v), (b1, b2) -> b1)
  .execute();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why the combiner is needed, since it doesn't actually do anything? :P Otherwise, thanks for your help, it works :)

Comment: it seems the Api has changed meanwhile. .reduce(userLoginBatch, (b, v) -> b.bind(v.toArray()), (b1, b2) -> b1) worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using reduce here abuses the API as your accumulator is not associative and your identity is not the actual identity. If you are already using jOOQ, it seems quite natural to use [jOOL](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) which [`foldLeft`](http://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.5/org/jooq/lambda/Seq.html#foldLeft-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method is more suitable here:

```
Seq.seq(userLoginsToPersist)
   .map(login ->
     Arrays.asList(login.getUsername(), login.getIp(), login.getMac(),
                  login.getLogin(), login.getStatus(), login.getApplication(),
                  login.getEntertainmentCredentialsId(), login.getVersion()))
   .foldLeft(userLoginBatch, (a, b) -> a.bind(b))
   .execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code will be much simpler if you use the `forEach` method:

```
userLoginsToPersist.forEach(login ->
    userLoginBatch.bind(login.getUsername(), login.getIp(), login.getMac(), login.getLogin(), login.getStatus(), login.getApplication(), login.getEntertainmentCredentialsId(), login.getVersion()));
userLoginBatch.execute();
```